# Is there a limit to the number of namespaces I can use in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm guessing the answer is no because there is no limit specified in the documentation but I'm a bit confused because the namespace selection shows up as a dropdown in the Google Cloud console, implying that there shouldn't be more namespaces than can fit in a dropdown menu.

Basically I want to know it is OK to have a billion namespaces if I make one namespace for each user I have and I have a billion users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each entity in the Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it. The key consists of the following components:
>
> - The namespace of the entity, which allows for multitenancy
> - The kind of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Datastore queries
> - An identifier for the individual entity, which can be either

Since the namespace is just a part of the key (prefix), there is definitely no limit on the max number of namespaces as to Cloud Datastore.

Furthermore, to create namespaces on a per-user or a per-client basis is very often typical application of namespaces. You can find more details in App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Creating_namespaces_on_a_per_user_basis).

Answer (score 0):

You can have many namespaces as you want, but at some point some features will stop working as well. For example, the stats auto generated by the datastore will stop generating namespace level stats (e.g. # of entities in a specific namespace).